# Avoid being put [on-hold/close]: What are the required question elements in order to be evidently clear?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

Have posted a question on `Unix&Linux` in which I described what the inconsistent symptoms of a critical Debian-Linux behavior is [here: **"How to alter Memory/RAM errors on Linux Debian 8 Jessie [closed]"**](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/302282/how-to-alter-memory-ram-errors-on-linux-debian-8-jessie). I invested much time trying to solve it by doing research, experimenting with proposed solutions, and exposing the detailed description of the symptoms.

First the question was put "on-hold", arguing that it would be "**`unclear what you're asking`**". I'm not really sure if all the five voters read the post carefully. However, I've adapted some parts as well as the title -- as described in the [Help Center advices](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions) --, trying to conform with the request. Now the question turned closed. The reason remains unchanged.

My reputation is not high. However, I'm not new to `StackExchange`, asked many questions, and no-one considered my questions "unclear". Consequently I find this "unclear" labeling arbitrary -- and certainly more unclear then the post itself.

Answer (score 4):

I guess the main issue is that it's hard to understand what your actual problem is. Are you asking how to fix your firefox issue? Are you asking for help in interpreting your memtest results? Both? Something else?

In general, when asking, it is a good idea to include a final sentence that clearly states what question you are trying to ask.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've read the [Help Center advices](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions) about "closed" questions. Roughly there are two invoked issues: "more information" and "more specific". The first is improbable -- since I've provided much information about the behavior. The second I've addressed on my edit after being put "on-hold". I've changed also the title to become _very_ specific. The Firefox issue in the beginning is a symptom... as well as the inconsistent RAM measurement. I'm not sure if repeating the title at the end would change specificity.

Comment: @alex You need to make the question specific. Do you want to *alter* the RAM problems? I assume you mean *fix*, by the way, not *alter*. You should also include the screenshots in your post, that would help clarify. In any case, your title is about RAM issues, then the only symptom you describe in the body is about firefox and the RAM issue is only on off site screenshots. It really isn't easy to understand what you're asking. To tell you the truth, I still don't know.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I will change "alter" with "fix". There are screenshots under "oddity" you find [this](http://www.ultraimg.com/image/1geB). To cut it short: My impression is that this issue could be solved more effectively by commenting below the question -- rather then putting me (harshly) "on-hold". The displayed reaction of at least the first of the moderators was imprecise. On the other hand -- after editing -- I've commented my post asking for feedback regarding the quality of the changes. This was ignored -- becoming "closed".

Comment: @alex just for clarification: i) none of the users who voted to close were moderators (those have a ♦ after their name, like I do) ii) when a question is put on hold, it is only so the asker can improve it. If the question is not reopened, "on hold" automatically changes to "closed". There was no further human intervention. Each time you edit your closed question, it will automatically be placed in the reopen queue where users can vote to reopen it. Just try and make it as clear as possible.

Comment: Thank you (I mean it sincerely). I'm also aware that you are sincerely trying to help me. So -- since we are on meta -- the solution of the question could be how to systematically increase the quality of the questions and/or feedback process. You answered me and I wrote you why I'm inclined to think that my question specificity is not as much of a reason. Maybe there are also other opinions (therefore I've made no edits on the original post after posting this issue), maybe they are not. While waiting 4 answers, I commented your answer in order to be polite and read more opinions.